# RallyRestAPI querying ScopedAttributeDefinition types

Tags: java, rest, rally, agile

Using the RallyRestAPI, is there a way to query ScopedAttributeDefinition types? This appears to define custom datatypes in Rally. I am trying to build a data dictionary of the custom types we use in Rally and associate these custom types to the object they are attributes of. (In case that doesn't make sense, here's an example: We have a custom field called Enabler Lead on Rally PortfolioItems. I'd like to query Rally for all custom fields for PortfolioItem and get the Enabler Field, and its metadata, from the Rally REST API.)

I'm using the Java client.

Comment: A ScopedAttributeDefinition is really just a view of another attribute in the system from a specific scope (workspace or project).  It allows you to see if a given attribute is hidden or required at that specific scope.  Is that the data you're after?

Comment: I need both the existence of the attribute, and its metadata (such as visible or hidden, type, accepted values, etc). 

Right now I'm querying all TypeDefinitions in the workspace, and getting its list of Attributes. This does not return custom data types such as the Enabler Lead field described above (all returned datatypes have "Custom=false").

Comment: from looking at the toolkit source i'm not totally convinced that it will even allow you to query for scoped attribute definitions unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I filed a github issue to add support for the ScopedAttributeDefinition: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/issues/19

In the meantime though you can work around it by using the underlying http client directly.  This code queries for all projects in your workspace and then finds the type definition for Portfolio Item and then for each project grabs all the custom attribute defs via the scopedattributedefinition endpoint and prints out their hidden/required status.

```
    QueryRequest projectQuery = new QueryRequest("project");
    projectQuery.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    QueryResponse projectResponse = restApi.query(projectQuery);

    QueryRequest typeDefQuery = new QueryRequest("typedefinition");
    typeDefQuery.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "Portfolio Item"));
    QueryResponse typeDefResponse = restApi.query(typeDefQuery);
    JsonObject piTypeDef = typeDefResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

    for(JsonElement projectResult : projectResponse.getResults()) {
        JsonObject project = projectResult.getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("Project: " + project.get("Name").getAsString());

        //Begin hackery (note we're not handling multiple pages-
        // if you have more than 200 custom attributes you'll have to page
        String scopedAttributeDefUrl = "/project/" + project.get("ObjectID").getAsLong() +
            "/typedefinition/" + piTypeDef.get("ObjectID").getAsLong() + "/scopedattributedefinition" +
            "?fetch=Hidden,Required,Name&query=" + URLEncoder.encode("(Custom = true)", "utf-8");
        String attributes = restApi.getClient().doGet(scopedAttributeDefUrl);
        QueryResponse attributeResponse = new QueryResponse(attributes);
        //End hackery

        for(JsonElement customAttributeResult : attributeResponse.getResults()) {
            JsonObject customAttribute = customAttributeResult.getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.print("\tAttribute: " + customAttribute.get("Name").getAsString());
            System.out.print(", Hidden: " + customAttribute.get("Hidden").getAsBoolean());
            System.out.println(", Required: " + customAttribute.get("Required").getAsBoolean());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Any other info you'd like for each of those custom fields should be accessible just by querying the Attributes collection from the piTypeDef.